# this signal is connected to multiple drivers

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, ise

```
    library ieee;
    use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;  
    use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;              
    use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

    entity ctrl_unit is
    port(   clock_cu:   in  std_logic;
        rst_cu:     in  std_logic;
        PCld_cu:    in  std_logic;
        mdata_out:  in  std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        dpdata_out: in  std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        maddr_in:   out     std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);        
        immdata:    out     std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        RFs_cu:     out std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
        RFwa_cu:    out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        RFr1a_cu:   out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        RFr2a_cu:   out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        RFwe_cu:    out std_logic;
        RFr1e_cu:   out std_logic;
        RFr2e_cu:   out std_logic;
        jpen_cu:    out     std_logic;
        ALUs_cu:    out std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);   
        Mre_cu:     out     std_logic;
        Mwe_cu:     out     std_logic;
        oe_cu:      out     std_logic
    );
    end ctrl_unit;

    architecture struct of ctrl_unit is

    component controller is
    port(   clock:      in std_logic;
        rst:        in std_logic;
        IR_word:    in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        RFs_ctrl:   out std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
        RFwa_ctrl:  out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        RFr1a_ctrl: out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        RFr2a_ctrl: out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        RFwe_ctrl:  out std_logic;
        RFr1e_ctrl: out std_logic;
        RFr2e_ctrl: out std_logic;                       
        ALUs_ctrl:  out std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);    
        jmpen_ctrl: out std_logic;
        PCinc_ctrl: out std_logic;
        PCclr_ctrl: out std_logic;
        IRld_ctrl:  out std_logic;
        Ms_ctrl:    out std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
        Mre_ctrl:   out std_logic;
        Mwe_ctrl:   out std_logic;
        oe_ctrl:    out std_logic
    );
    end component;

    component IR is
    port(   IRin:       in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        IRld:       in std_logic;
        dir_addr:   out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        IRout:      out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0)
    );  
    end component;

    component PC is   
    port(   PCld:   in std_logic;
        PCinc:  in std_logic;
        PCclr:  in std_logic;
        PCin:   in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        PCout:  out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0)
    );
    end component;   

    component bigmux is
    port(   Ia:     in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        Ib:     in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        Ic: in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        Id: in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        Option: in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
        Muxout: out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0)
    );
    end component;

    signal IR_sig: std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    signal PCinc_sig, PCclr_sig, IRld_sig: std_logic;
    signal Ms_sig: std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
    signal PC2mux: std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    signal IR2mux_a, IR2mux_b: std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);

    begin

      IR2mux_a <= "00000000" & IR_sig(7 downto 0);
      IR2mux_b <= "000000000000" & IR_sig(11 downto 8); 
      immdata <= IR2mux_a;

      U0: controller port map(  clock_cu,rst_cu,IR_sig,RFs_cu,RFwa_cu,
                     RFr1a_cu,RFr2a_cu,RFwe_cu,RFr1e_cu,
                     RFr2e_cu,ALUs_cu,jpen_cu,PCinc_sig,
                     PCclr_sig,IRld_sig,Ms_sig,Mre_cu,Mwe_cu,oe_cu);
      U1: PC port map(PCld_cu, PCinc_sig, PCclr_sig, IR2mux_a, PC2mux);
      U2: IR port map(mdata_out, IRld_sig, IR2mux_a, IR_sig);
      U3: bigmux port map(dpdata_out,IR2mux_a,PC2mux,IR2mux_b,Ms_sig,maddr_in);

    end struct;
```

I have a vhdl code like above but when i try to implement it, it show error like this: 
[image]

can anyone please tell me what i'm doing wrong here? thanks.

Comment: Hint,  drivers means outputs of your components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off:

```
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;              
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
```

Baaaad. these are non-standardized libraries (even though they are named "ieee.std"). Instead use:

```
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
```

... if required. But in this case you are not doing any arithmetic *at all*. So why include these libraries??

---

Next, it is no longer required to define component interfaces in architectures. Instead of:

```
architecture arch of ent is
    component foo is
        port(
            [...]
        );
    end component;
begin
    inst_foo : foo
        port map (
            [...]
        );
```

You can just type:

```
architecture arch of ent is
begin
    inst_foo : entity work.foo
        port map (
            [...]
        );
```

---

Also, please use full assignment in port and generic mappings: it saves errors when changing the entities. So not:

```
inst : comp port map (a, b, c);
```

But

```
inst : comp port map (in1 => a, in2 => b, out1 => c);
```

---

finally, multiple assignments. For example look at these lines:

```
  IR2mux_a <= "00000000" & IR_sig(7 downto 0);
  U2: IR port map(mdata_out, IRld_sig, IR2mux_a, IR_sig);
```

In the second line `IR2mux_a` is the third argument: that is an *output* port of the component `IR`! So the signal `IR2mux_a` is both driven by the component `IR` and by the assignment in the first line.

Answer (score 1):

Those signals are assigned values in multiple places. Change the code so they are only assigned in one place. One of them is assigned a value from another signal and it is connected to the output of a module. Pick one. Maybe you need different signals and a much of some sort.